# How to easily label point values in ArcScene?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, labeling, arcscene

I would like to be able to quickly label point values in my scene.

I am aware of the fact that there is no out-of-the-box solution to label features in ArcScene similar to the one in ArcMap. (No doubt the 3D environment is presenting a lot of complexity to the programmers.)

I've worked with some (expensive) programs that were able to successfully and cleanly label feature in 3D environment but redrawing/refreshing was required to update the labels. (Gemcom GEMS)

I do not need my points to rotate correctly with the scene or anything as fancy as that however I am a little tired of placing text manually in the scene or in post-processing.

Does anyone know of a working solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is amazing tool, it works in ArcScene 10.2 just follow [this link](http://wolfmapper.wordpress.com/2012/09/10/creating-feature-labels-in-arcscene-10-1/) (or [this archived link](https://web.archive.org/web/20141115122241/http://wolfmapper.wordpress.com/2012/09/10/creating-feature-labels-in-arcscene-10-1/)).
[image: GEOLOGIC CROSS SECTION WITH POINTS LABELS]

Comment: I was skeptical but this is in fact fully functional in ArcGIS 10.2.1.  I don't understand why ESRI would not make this into a regular toolbar just like they did with TIN Editing.

Comment: Any chance that you remember how he did it? Because the site is offline for good.

Comment: Any other source of this? As @AndrewLebron pointed out, the site is offline and the tool would be much appreciated.

Comment: For me, this worked http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/8.3/Samples/3D%20Analyst/3D%20Visualization/3D%20Text/Label3DToolbar/Label3DToolbar.htm
It is not that easy to install and I had to deal with *.dll and *ocx issues but I managed in the end. If you experience a comdlg32.ocx issue this is helpful too: http://www.bioinformatics.org/snp-tools-excel/install_comdlg32.htm

Answer (score 6):

There is some VB code on EDN

*"This tool contains a toolbar providing functionality to create text labels in the 3D environment of ArcScene. The text and location of the labels of the toolbar can be originated from features in a layer, as well as by user defined positions via mouse clicks. Dialogs are provided to allow the modification of the rotation, offset, and orientation of the labels. The labels can also be saved and opened into ArcScene documents via the toolbar. "*

http://edn.esri.com/index.cfm?fa=codeExch.sampleDetail&pg=/arcobjects/9.1/Samples/3D_Analyst/Visualization/ArcScene/Text_Toolbar/Label_3D_Toolbar.htm

There is also the 3D Graphic Toolbar[image]

Note:
Three-dimensional text in ArcScene can only be displayed as a **3D object**. ArcScene does not support 2D text graphics that are billboarded to always face the viewer or set to rasterize on the surface.

Comment: Nice. Thanks. It will take some time to make that into a version 10 add-on but I will take a closer look at the code and build one. Sounds like exactly what I was looking for.  As for the 3D graphic tool; I've used that but it's a pain with multiple features.