# Why ArcGIS application does not have label manager?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, labeling, arcscene

[image]

Why is there no label manager in the pictured application of ArcGIS for Desktop?

Answer (score 5):

That's ArcScene, not ArcMap, and as such has no real labelling abilities. However there are plugins.

See this plugin for one potential solution: http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.0/Samples/3D_Analyst/Visualization/ArcScene/Text_Toolbar/LABEL_3D_TOOLBAR.htm

and
https://geonet.esri.com/thread/96511

And also this answer:
[How to easily label point values in ArcScene?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13239/how-to-easily-label-point-values-in-arcscene)